# Is the any way to find my stolen Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, security

Two weeks ago, my 13" Macbook Pro was stolen. Is there any way to locate my laptop if and when the thief accesses the internet?

Is there any application or a website similar to [this](http://store.apple.com/us/product/TS294LL/A) that can give me an alert message if I register my Macbook pro ID number?

Comment: I have edited the title as this applies to all macs. Your MacBook Pro has a camera so that's a bonus if the software installed allows you to snap a picture which may help you locate it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If your machine was password protected, you might be out of luck. If not, there are a few possibilities.

If you have SSH enabled that *might* be an option. Also, if you had any remote access programs installed, like TeamViewer or LogMeIn, you have a chance to find it, assuming it's connected to the internet.

Regardless, I suggest contacting Apple and telling them the serial number of the machine and that it was stolen. If it's brought in for service, you *might* be able to get it back. (Although Apple has no official policy on this, it doesn't hurt to tell them. I contacted them when my iMac was stolen. Like I said, not much help, but it's better than nothing.)

PS: Check [this](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=hacker+stolen+mac+ssh) out. You might find it inspiring at least.

Comment: Great information. I did install Team Viewer and my system is not password protected. Any information from here?

Comment: You will need to be able log in to your machine remotely through TeamViewer. Do you remember your machine ID? Do you have access to machines that connected to your machine so you can grab that number? Did you set a predefined password? Those are some questions that need to be answered to know how "recoverable" your machine is.

Comment: I do not know about these information. I'll send an email to apple to send me those information if possible.

Comment: Apple can't help you with your TeamViewer information. You need to have that.

Comment: I have all the information about my system. Is there any possibility now? I just found my Apple Mac-book pro box, it has all the information.

Comment: @karthik I'm referring to the information in TeamViewer, not on your Apple box.

Comment: So; back when my home was broken into and I lost a macbook pro apple wouldn't take a report of a stolen ipod touch nor macbook; they only take reports from police officers with a case file. That was also done but nothing came of it.

Comment: Apple will not recover your laptop for you if you report it as stolen.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck getting this taken care of.  In the future (as in your next machine) there are a couple of things you can do.

I use prey from http://preyproject.com/ and it allows remote locking, reporting, and gps coordinates.  Prey is great and works on my mobile phone as well.

I also use backblaze for offsite backup and they offer a "Locate My Computer" option here http://blog.backblaze.com/2011/05/23/lost-your-computer-get-it-back-backblaze-launches-locate-my-computer/

There are other pay options out there (lojack) but I have no experience with them.

Comment: Thank you very much. I certainly use these application for my next Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Gmail or Dropbox (and you don't already have anti theft software already installed) then you might be able to track your Macbook's IP Address.

If your macbook was stolen, you can use a service like Gmail or Dropbox to find the IP address of your thief. When you log into those services from any computer, it logs the IP address used, and displays your last used IP in your account. In Gmail, it's in the bottom right-hand corner under "Details," and in Dropbox, it's in Settings > Security under the details of each individual computer. If the thief used your computer, the last logged IP address may be theirs instead of yours. Again, though, if they're smart, they didn't use your computer and this trick won't work.

Of course, knowing their IP only gets you so far. You'd still have to file a police report, send a subpoena to that IP addresse's internet provider, and find out where they're located, which could take a long time. Using this method is no guarantee unfortunately Whatever you do, don't try to track the thief down yourself and get your gear back. That could lead to all sorts of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for an iCloud account.

Log in with your iCloud account on all your iPods,iPhones,Macs, and iPads.

Now go to iCloud.com and Log in.

You will be able to use Find My iPhone to track all of your iPods,iPhones,Macs, and iPads.

Too bad for you that you didn't already have an iCloud account. Use this method when you purchase your new mac products.

Also, use a kensington lock to secure your devices and reduce theft. Install some software like ilostfinder or Aobo Keylogger will help too.
http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-trace-stolen-macbook-use-find-my-mac-find-stolen-macbook-3493958/