# MacBook stolen, which data is accessible to the thief?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, security

2014 13" MBP got stolen. Find My Mac wasn't on (stupid mistake), so they only thing protecting my data is the password.

If they do manage to get in somehow, then I can't protect my files but I don't want them to get into my iCloud (Notes/Photos/Keychain/etc.), I've changed my iCloud password so that should prevent them from accessing anything right?

All advice is welcome, I've already filed the police report but recovering the laptop seems unlikely

Comment: Did you have firevault turned on?  If not it is [trivial](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61905/how-can-i-reset-a-macs-password-from-single-user-mode) for them to change the password from single user mode.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298642 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305471 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18241

Comment: @lx07 I'm not sure if FileVault was turned on, is there any way of checking that if I don't have the computer anymore? And could you explain how they could change the password, and if that gives them access to my data or is it more like a clean wipe?

Comment: "how to change the password" is explained in the link in the first comment. Once it's changed they can access all the data stored on your computer.

Comment: @nohillside I see that they can get in my computer's data, but regarding iCloud data, as long as I've changed that password, they should no longer have access to it, correct?